# Find which physical disks are in virtual disk from CLI

Tags: raid, command-line-interface, dell-openmanage

I have the following virtual disk :

```shell
# omreport storage vdisk controller=0 vdisk=14
Virtual Disk 14 on Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)

Controller PERC H730 Mini (Embedded)
ID                                : 14
Status                            : Ok
Name                              : VirtualDisk14
State                             : Ready
Hot Spare Policy violated         : Not Applicable
Encrypted                         : No
Layout                            : RAID-0
Size                              : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
T10 Protection Information Status : No
Associated Fluid Cache State      : Not Applicable
Device Name                       : /dev/sdn
Bus Protocol                      : SAS
Media                             : HDD
Read Policy                       : No Read Ahead
Write Policy                      : Force Write Back
Cache Policy                      : Not Applicable
Stripe Element Size               : 64 KB
Disk Cache Policy                 : Disabled

#
```

From the CLI, how can I find which physical disks are in my virtual disk ?

Comment: There is a script to found pdisk belongs to each vdisk on this link. Is this what you want?
[link](https://www.aglt2.org/wiki/AGLT2/MD3460Install)

Comment: @librhnylmz I've been through that [tools/storage_details.sh script](https://www.aglt2.org/wiki/AGLT2/MD3460Install#A_useful_script) but could find the part where I could link the physical disks to a virtual disk, can you please tell where it is ?

Comment: this part of the script: `#  Assemble the list of pdisks in each vdisk
## omreport storage pdisk controller=1 vdisk=1`

Comment: @librhnylmz Thanks a lot : `# omreport storage pdisk controller=0 vdisk=15 | grep Physical.Disk
List of Physical Disks belonging to SYSTEM
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:12
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:13
`
Can you please convert your latest comment to an answer and add the following example to that answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find which physical disks are in your virtual disk with below command.

```
omreport storage pdisk controller=1 vdisk=1
```